# Problem after using diplace modifer

Tags: displacement

I used displace modifier to give some uneven effect. and after that my modeling looks like crashed (or though, I tried to follow the instruction on utube, I might have made mistakes;)
so I searched this site. and some post says, 'remove doubles' but it still doesn't work;
Can I fix this? I even can not get a clue where this bad meshes come from;
 [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank your for your kind offer! but..... somehow I overwrote the file;; and I made it all over again. and now problem solved ㅠㅠ...I think I might commit an elementary error.  anyway, really thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model looks choppy, too. Subdivide it more as Displace modifier needs **many** subdivisions to give satisfactory results.

Comment: oh, so I had it increased, now it looks better. thank for your precious time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of the faces of your object have normals facing inside. You can try going into edit mode, selecting everything and pressing Ctrl+N or Mesh>Normals>Recalculate Outside.